# VS2013 Express: Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.IO.Stream'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I cannot use essential things in Visual Studio Express 2013 (VB)
I have had an experience with VS2005 and VS2008 but in 2013 it seems everything is changed. I can't write any simple app.

`My` namespace doesn't work

`WebClient` class not present.
and many others things causes a problems anywhere

A fresh example a faced right now. I trying to write a sub which writes a byte array into a file through StreamWriter. In MSDN it said that it can work with string as parameter. So, my code is:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim bytes As Byte() = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
    Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("FileName") ' (TA-DA!!!) "Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.IO.Stream'"
        sw.Write(bytes)
        sw.Flush()
    End Using
End Sub
```

What most important is that example should works perfect according official MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2 but in fact it doesn't.

Comment: What kind of project do you have? Is it windows store app?

Comment: It seems that I have store app (Windows 8.1)?

Comment: If you check MSDN page, you can see that constructor accepting string is not supported in windows store apps. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - Version Information block.

Comment: Thank you. Wouldn't you please share a link? I heard that the architecture in windows store apps have changed but I have no idea that this is so hard to accept.

Comment: You just downloaded the wrong version of Express.  Use the one named "for Desktop".  The "for Windows" version requires you to relearn .NET programming.  Use "for Web" if you want to create web sites.